# How to force skip the verify_authenticity_token in development mode

Tags: plugins, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a plugin that hits the POST urls of an application with a set of predefined parameters set by the user. The problem is I cannot bypass the InvalidAuthenticityToken exception and hence I need to forcefully skip the filter by adding this code snippet.

```
def self.included(klass)
 klass.extend ClassMethods  

 klass.class_eval do      
   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token      
   puts "eval done"
 end 

 filters = klass._process_action_callbacks.select{|c| c.kind == :before}
 filters.each {|f| puts "active filters #{f.filter}"}
end
```

However this does not skip the filters though the snippet

```
filters = klass._process_action_callbacks.select{|c| c.kind == :before}
 filters.each {|f| puts "active filters #{f.filter}"}
```

does not display `verify_authentication_token` as an active filter. I am not sure if I am missing something. Would really appreciate some help.